# PHP variable mixed with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am getting a bit lost on a personal project and looking for some help.  I found a cURL code that will get the Google+ count for a specific URL, and it is working great when hard coding the url you are trying to get.  I am trying to run this script based on form data using GET. See working and non working examples below.  I am also bolding the line of code that I am changing.

**WORKS**

```
*$url = "http://mashable.com";

 $ch = curl_init();  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $url . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));


 $curl_results = curl_exec ($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);

 $parsed_results = json_decode($curl_results, true);

 echo $parsed_results[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'];
```

**Doesn't Work**

```
$url = $_GET['url'];

 $ch = curl_init();  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $url . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));


 $curl_results = curl_exec ($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);

 $parsed_results = json_decode($curl_results, true);

 echo $parsed_results[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'];
```

Comment: what are the contents of `$_GET['url']`?  Use `urlencode($url)` in the `curl_setopt()`

Comment: The $_GET['url'] = the exact same http://mashable.com.  I tried, urlencode, it made no difference.

Comment: They are _exactly_ the same, if you `var_dump($_GET['url'])`?

Comment: Identical:

**string(19) "http://mashable.com" 
string(19) "http://mashable.com"**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on one of my recent projects using cURL.

It turned out that while trying to load a URL using cURL, I had to include either the `http://` and/or the `www.` part of the URL. Without them, cURL would not open the URL. I eventually coded a script that would try the different combinations of these as not all sites responded to one particular combo.

I see from your last comment that the URL in your `var_dump` contains neither of these. If you add them then hopefully this will resolve your issue.